# Eaton 3 way dimmer switch

Tags: dimmer-switch

[image: Other outlet][image: Outlet]Replacing an old 3 way switch with a new dimmer 3 way switch. The old switch had 2 traveler wires connected to it (black and red), the ground wire, and the 'hot' wire. I also noticed 2 neutral wires (both white) that were bundled together and capped. Now, the new dimmer switch has the green screw (for the ground wire), and then 2 screws on each side. According to the instructions, the top left is 'neutral', the bottom left is for a traveler, the top right is for the hot wire, and the bottom right is for another neutral wire. So I'm a bit confused here - I have 2 traveler wires but only one spot on the new switch for one. There are 2 spots for neutral wires, but they are bundled together in the outlet. Thanks

FYI - this is an Eaton WFD30 smart universal dimmer...
Edit: In the pic, the 2 white wires were bundled together and capped (assume they are both neutrals), the black and red are travelers and the other white with the black tape was the 'hot' wire.

Edit 2: Added a pic of the other outlet.  Looks to be wired slightly differently than the one I was installing the dimmer on.  I can out the dimmer on this one, whatever is easier.  This one appears to have 3 white wires bundled together.

Comment: We still need photos of the insides of the boxes in order to be able to help you.  Also, please use the [edit] button in "share edit ..." at the bottom left of your post to add the photos to your post instead of creating a new post

Comment: Looks like just 2 relevant cables in this box (obviously there is another cable to the other switch). That would be a slightly different setup from what I described in my answer. **Please post a picture of the other 3-way switch and all its wires (but don't disconnect anything).**

Comment: Key, important questions: **The white wire taped black: Is that going into the red wire nut, and if so, what color is the wire it connects to?** If that is black then I think I know what is going on. If it is white then I'm not so sure. Second question: **Do you know which switch has incoming power vs. which switch connects to the fixture?**

Comment: Yes, it's white

Comment: I am very confused about the white-marked-black-connected-to-white wire. It can't be neutral (neutral isn't switched), so it must be incoming hot (can't be - that should *never* be white) or switched hot. Switched hot is sometimes white-marked-black. But it should be going to black to the fixture, not white. I'm either a lot more confused than usual or something was originally wired incorrectly.

Comment: So if this helps at all, I originally wired a 3 way smart switch (not a dimmer), and it was a piece of cake. It had a neutral wire on it, so I connected that to the 2 white wires and bundled all 3 together.  It had 2 spots for traveler wires, and a spot for the hot wire.  So everything got connected easily and it worked.  But we wanted a dimmer instead so I pulled it out....

Comment: That helps a **huge** amount. This confirms that the "hot" wire really is a hot wire, because otherwise your smart switch would not have worked. Revising answer...

Comment: Actually, this presents a problem. Need to have one traveler (red) plus hot (black) plus switched hot (white - connect to load) go across to switch 2 to fixture. But that doesn't fit with what I see. Something still ain't right.

Comment: So I tried connecting the 2 travelers wires to the bottom left and top right, the 2 white (neutral) wires to the top left, and the hot (black tape) wire to the bottom right, and I can turn the light on using the other switch, but not with the dimmer switch...

Comment: I gave up, lol Installed a regular 3 way dimmer switch and took about 5 minutes to install - appreciate all the replies!

Answer (score 0):

The answers are all in [the manual](https://www.eaton.com/content/dam/eaton/products/wiring-devices-and-connectivity/wiring-devices/wi-fi-smart-devices/wi-fi-smart-universal-dimmer-spec-sheet.pdf)

An *ordinary* 3-way switch uses two travelers. A smart switch doesn't necessarily need two travelers, and this one doesn't. There is an accessory switch available to let you dim at *both* locations. But assuming you are replacing one 3-way switch with the dimmer and the other one is staying the same, you wire according to *Two Location Control Using a 3-Way Switch*.

- Top Left = Neutral (white, connected to the existing white bundle)
- Top Right = Hot (note, this must be true hot, not "switched hot")
- Bottom Right = Load, also known as "switched hot".
- Bottom Left = Traveler. Yes, just *one* traveler.

This is almost certainly doable, since you have the sometimes elusive neutral available in the box. But it may get tricky. Specifically, typical configuration is that one of the 3-way switches will connect to two travelers and hot, and the other to two travelers and switched hot. But this smart switch needs to connect to *both* hot and switched hot, and the ordinary 3-way switch needs to connect to hot.

**Note: Major changes to original answer, now that OP posted a second picture.**

It looks now like this is either:

- Power -> switch 2 -> switch 1 -> fixture

or

- Power -> switch 1 -> switch 2 -> fixture

(My original answer had power and fixture both connecting in the switch 1 box.)

Basic answer will still be along the lines of:

- Use one traveler as a "signal"
- Use the other (former) traveler as a way to get hot (not switched) between the boxes

But the specifics will vary depending on exactly what is going on. In particular, determination of which switch connects to power and which switch connects to the fixture.